# How to change custom Check Box border with Dart

Tags: html, css, dart

When an event occurs I want to change the color of the border of a custom check box. 
The HTML is:

```
      <input id='B12' type='checkbox' class='checkbox' checked='checked'>
        <label for='B12'>B12&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <input id='B10' type='checkbox' class='checkbox' checked='checked'>
        <label for='B10'>B10&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <input id='B8' type='checkbox' class='checkbox' checked='checked'>
        <label for='B8'>B8&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <input id='BBW' type='checkbox' class='checkbox' checked='checked'>
        <label for='BBW'>Wide&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label:before {
  outline: 0;
  border: 2px solid #F8F8E0;
  content: url(resources/CheckBoxUnchecked.png);
  display: inline-block;
  font: 24px/1em sans-serif;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 0 .25em 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 24px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
  border: 2px solid #077313;
  background: #00ff00;
  content: url(resources/CheckBoxOK.png); /* icon */
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Using Dart I have a list of the checkboxes and then loop through them with the intention of changing the border to red if they are checked (and displaying a particular image). The commented out line and variations of it that I have tried do not work.  How do I access and change the border?  I'm new at this ...

Dart:

```
final checkBoxes = querySelectorAll('[class=checkbox]');
// later
for(; whichImage < 4; whichImage++){
  if(checkBoxes[whichImage].checked) {
    imageElement.src = imageList[whichImage];
    // checkBoxes[whichImage].border = '1px solid red';
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

see
[How to style checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css/4148544#4148544)

**original answer**

You can set style properties directly using

```dart
checkBoxes[whichImage].style  
    //..border = '1px solid red'; // either this way or
  ..borderWidth = '1px'
  ..borderStyle = 'solid'
  ..borderColor = 'red';
```

External styles are usually the preferred way (like showed by @sunglim)

Comment: Neither style works for me.  Perhaps I should just attempt to change the label text color (or background?). I intend to restore the original color as soon as another image ls loaded.

Comment: You are right, I encountered this myself a while ago. Just forgot that this applies here. This is a CSS/Browser problem, this has nothing to do with Dart. The checkbox element just doesn't allow to be manipulated much by style attributes. There are a lot of customized checkboxes out there and they all (as far as I know) use an approach where they make the default checkbox appearance invisble and provide a custom implementation of it's appearance (often CSS only). See the link of my updated answer.

Comment: I'm marking this solved.  I have another solution that doesn't involve the border and I'll revisit the problem when I learn more CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Add Css.

```
.CheckedCss {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

From Dart side,

```
   ...

   querySelectedDom.classes.add('CheckedCss');

   ...
```

Comment: I think that's jQuery of which I know nothing and I'm guessing that it will attempt to color the border of all the checks, not just the one.

Comment: No, this is dart code. See https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-dom-html.Element@id_classes